# Can't access dimension z of a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arraylist

I have a 3d image stored in fet_img np array. The size is (400,400,74).

I want to access the 74 2D images seperately, each of size (400,400).

I would expect that this would do the trick:

```
fet_img[:][:][0]
```

However, when I print the shape of this, I get (400,74)

I tried

```
fet_img[0][:][:]
```

and

```
fet_img[:][0][:]
```

but the size of all three of these are (400,74)...
I'm overlooking something but I can't quite figure out what?

Note: I'm runnning this from a local jupyter notebook and all values are dtype('float64') if that matters at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `fet_img[:, :, 0]` instead.